# invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (Ruby 1.9 + rails 2.3.8 + mongodb + mongo_mapper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

My setup is:

linux + Ruby 1.9 + rails 2.3.8 + mongodb + mongo_mapper

I followed http://railscasts.com/episodes/194-mongodb-and-mongomapper, that everything is OK first. I can insert English strings successfully, but when I insert some Chinese strings, it inserted, but can't be displayed.

The web page shows an exception:

```
invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
```

I use `mongo` command to see the data in mongodb, and it's correct. But I don't know why rails can't display them.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please add the following lines in your environment.rb .

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

The problem will be solved.

Comment: Make sure to add these lines *inside* the config block.

Answer (score 18):

You may correct this error writing this

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

to your `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` or similar. It works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you!! I've been fighting Heroku with getting this Jekyll application to run for hours. I solved it with `heroku config:add LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: This also solves an issue in WebStorm 7 when using grunt from the embed command line with Jekyll.

Answer (score 5):

I had this error with a Rack application.

Adding

```
   Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8

   Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

to `config.ru` resolved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd $HOME
vi .bashrc
```

add locale conf below:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

save and run:
    source ~/.bashrc

Everything is okay~

Answer (score 0):

check your `locale` settings of your OS. You need to set up `en_US`.UTF-8` locale environment variable otherwise you may face this problem.

If you operating system is `Ubuntu` then you can check your `locale` by typing the following command.

```bash
sudo locale
```

and then you can re-configure your locale by typing the following command

```bash
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

It may help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I was using an older version of ruby. `rvm use 2.0` did the trick.