# jquery-rails Gem causing Heroku push to fail

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an Rails 3 app with the following in its gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'
```

which when I attempt to deploy to Heroku fails with the following

```
   Installing railties (3.0.5) 
   /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:519:in `normalize_yaml_input': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:479:in `from_yaml'
    ....
```

This seems to relate to the jquery-rails gem (removing it prevents the error and the app deploys correctly). I've tried it with and without a version specified and the problem still occurs.

Comment: Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192128/invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii-ruby-1-9-rails-2-3-8-mongodb-mongo-mapp

Comment: Thanks, I can't work out how to apply that as it doesn't happen on my test environment, only remotely when I try to deploy to Heroku but on switching to the Cedar stack it seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to create a new Heroku application with the cedar stack (using heroku create --stack cedar) and the gems then installed perfectly.

Comment: I was having the same issue with jquery-rails, this just solved it. +1

Comment: Just noticed tho, the cedar stack is running webrick... that sucks. With omniauth + google, I get the error for too large request...

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the jquery gem before the grouped gems.